# How to compare RL algorithms with different NN sizes?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, comparison, proximal-policy-optimization, soft-actor-critic

I wanted to run some tests with some RL algorithms in a continuous control task, namely PPO-clip and SAC.

When comparing their NN structures described in their papers, [SAC](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01290.pdf) used 2 layers with 256 neurons, while [PPO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) used 2 layers with 64 neurons each.

Can one compare these algorithms with these different NN sizes, "just like that"? I imagine a larger NN can approximate more complex functions and must be harder to train until convergence, compared to a smaller NN.

And in this case, the width of the NN differs a lot. It seems to me that the NN size is rather ignored when comparing, or am I missing something?